# Trying to get an Indian visa as an Indian-born Canadian citizen who never held an indian passport

Tags: visas, passports, india

I immigrated to Canada when I was 4 under my mother’s passport, and obtained Canadian citizenship within 6 years, all before the year 2000. I never had an Indian passport.

I’ve been to India since, the e-Visa process always seemed to be fine.

This time though, I had to use the paper visa, and they are asking me for proof of renunciation of Indian citizenship. I tried providing my mother’s, which includes my name under the Minors category, and providing my citizenship certificate which has the year I was made a Canadian citizen, but it was rejected and they want proof of renunciation.

I tried to start the application, but it requires me to go surrender my passport at Passport Seva… I am at a loss, I have never had an Indian passport. I can set the passport number to “00000” or “LOST” but every affidavit assumes I have a passport instead of never having had one. Is there a correct process for people like me who obtained foreign citizenship without ever having an Indian passport?

Comment: Not having a passport is not the same as not being a citizen (the vast majority of Indian citizens don’t have a passport). I suppose you were an Indian citizen by birth, but your current status depends a lot on chronology (you may still be an Indian citizen). Can you give dates of your birth and your mother’s renunciation? Did your father renounce citizenship as well?

Comment: I am guessing, as you traveled under your mother's passport, it was your passport too. You mother would have had to surrender it at that time as per the law. Do you have any copies of those records, tickets (I know it is too much to expect) and the passport?

Comment: Wikipedia tells us “_Minor children lost citizenship only if their fathers (not mothers) relinquished that status until 1992_” which is one the reasons why exact chronology is important. If only OP’s mother relinquished Indian citizenship, and that happened before 1992, then OP is still an Indian citizen. Other situations may need different evidence.

Comment: Was your father an Indian citizen?

Answer (score 6):

As a former Indian citizen, you qualify for the [Overseas Citizenzhip of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_Citizenship_of_India) which is essentially a lifetime visa for a flat fee.

With the witholding of the indian e-Visa facility for Canadians, I highly suggest you applying for this instead of paper visas

Comment: It’s not even certain OP is a “former” Indian citizen. They may actually still be one.

Comment: He is still an Indian citizen. He was supposed to choose and renounce the citizenship at age of 18. That didn't happen. (This is my assumption. Need to contact indian highcommission or consulate in canada to confirm the next steps.)

Comment: @AnishSheela The OP says they were included as minors in their mother's renunciation.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Its not possible to renounce the Indian citizenship as a minor. Only case where an Indian citizen is allowed to keep dual citizenship is if the person is a minor. For example, a child born in US will be having dual US-Indian citizenship. At 18, they are supposed to renounce either of the citizenship. The OP's issue seems to be complicated and may have to contact Indian highcommision to resolve.

Comment: @anishSheela If a parent ceases to be an Indian citizen, all minor childrens ceases being Indian citizens at the same time, see point 1 in this official help [document](https://indiancitizenshiponline.nic.in/Renounce/Documents/Notice/ic_faq_16092021.pdf)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Oh! I was wrong.

Comment: @anishsheela But, I've just come across the comment from jcaron under OP's question, which may or may not have an impact. But, due to the fact that their name is written on the certificate, I doubt this is what's happening

Comment: @AnishSheela I don't suppose you were entirely wrong.  It's probably not possible for a minor to renounce Indian citizenship, but that's not exactly what happened in this case.

Comment: What happens if both parents are Indian citizens but only one renounces Indian citizenship?